# Is there a way i can import data from an external worksheet into the working sheet but import only a specific set of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a worksheet with column headings that match the same as the column headings of the worksheet i want to import. I only want to import the data from the imported worksheet that match the column headings of the worksheet i'm working on. For example i have 'supplier', 'SMA', and 'SKU' and i only want to import the data with those headings from the import sheet into the active worksheet

Comment: What version of Excel? You may be able to use Power Query.

Comment: i don't have power query. I have 2010 excel

Comment: Power Query is (according to [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-query-overview-and-learning-ed614c81-4b00-4291-bd3a-55d80767f81d)) available to download for Excel 2010.

Comment: thanks ben. i've now downloaded it however when i import the file how do i import it to the conditions that i set in my inquiry?

Comment: I think [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-data-from-external-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a) might be helpful.

Comment: thanks ben, i have been on this site which help me import it but would you know how to automate this query?